How to instruct Dependabot to ignore pre-releases or release candidate versions of a dependency?
I'm trying to set up Dependabot to keep our project Golang version up to date, but recently we received a PR from it to update our Golang version to a release candidate version (which is unwanted).
This is my dependabot.yml:
  - package-ecosystem: "gomod"
    directory: "/"
    schedule:
      interval: "weekly"
    allow:
      - dependency-name: "golang"
    ignore:
      - dependency-name: "golang"
        versions: ["*.*.*-rc.*"]

This config results in the following error: The property '#/updates/0/ignore/0/versions' includes invalid version requirements for a docker ignore condition
I've also tried:

versions: ["*.*.*-rc.*"]
versions: ["x.x.x-rc.x"]
versions: ["version-update:semver-pre-release"]

Nothing works.
How can I ignore beta, alpha, pre and rc versions?

https://docs.github.com/en/code-security/dependabot/dependabot-version-updates/configuration-options-for-the-dependabot.yml-file#specifying-dependencies-and-versions-to-ignore says "use the standard pattern for the package manager"

Isn't "*.*.*-rc.* a standard for Golang?

You're not using the Go ecosystem, according to the YAML you've shown: package-ecosystem: "docker".

I've just edited the question to reflect the gomod package-ecosystem. Still, same error.
